# Find real value $c$ such that $x^2 = c + \ln(x)$ has only one solution for $x$

Tags: calculus

> Find real value $c$ such that $x^2 = c + \ln(x)$ has only one solution for $x$.

I was discussing this question with one of my coworkers and we were stumped. I've tried simple algebraic methods for extracting $x$ from the variables, and upon inputting the problem into wolfram alpha, I receive a pair of roots with the Lambert $W$ function inside, which I do not know how to deal with. I was hoping someone with a bit more finesse and understanding of the function could tell me the value of $c$ which produces a single tangent point between the two functions as defined in the title... that is where the two roots are equal and completely real. Regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the function $f(x)=x^2-\ln(x)-c$. Do you see why, when there is exactly one zero of $f$, it has to be where $f$ attains its minimum?

Answer (score 0):

At the point of intersection, $ x^2 $ and $ c + \ln(x) $ have the same value and their derivatives do too.

$$ x^2 = c + \ln(x) $$
$$ 2x = \frac{1}{x} $$

Solving the second equation, you get $ x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $ and $ x = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $, but since the domain of $\ln(x)$ is only positives, reject the latter.

Now, simply plug in $ x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $ into the first equation and find $ c = \frac{1}{2} - \ln(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) $, or $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\ln2$.

If you graph the two functions (I checked on Desmos), you'll see they are indeed tangent to each other at one point only.

Comment: Could you explain why the derivatives must be equal? (Not my downvote, by the way. This is the way I solved it.)

Comment: Graphing is not a mathematically rigorous proof.

Answer (score -1):

1. Plot the graph of $y = k(x) = x^2$. [The blue dotted]
2. Plot the graphs of $y = \ln(x) + c$ for different values of $c$. [The red line is when $c = 10$, the green line is when $c = 0$ and the purple is when $c = -10$.]
3. The figure shows none of the lines plotted in (2) qualify.
4. The only solution is the grey dotted line which is tangent to $y = k(x)$. This is done by letting $c = 0.75$ (approximately).

---

Knowing the fact that they should be tangent to each other, we can find their slopes by differentiation to get ($2x$ and $1/x$). Equating the two, we get $x = \sqrt{1/2}$.

$c$ is given by $[\sqrt {1/2}]^2 = \ln(\sqrt {1/2}) + c$.

[image]

Comment: Is this a mathematically rigorous argument?

Comment: @Gary The first part is to investigate how the lines interact. See the added  part.